# OpenLayers 2.11 mixed content site blocked

Tags: https, openlayers

I have to change a domain from http to https. The running map application uses Openlayers 2.11. OL loads tile layers (Bing, Google, …) which using scripts served over http thus this site gets blocked (mixed content) in Chrome + Firefox.

For Example

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://viewer.example.com/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://ecn.t2.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a1202033.jpeg?g=3112'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS.

**I cannot upgrade Openlayers!**

What chance do I have? Is there a https Version of OL 2.11 or something like "forceSSL = true"?

Cheers,

motorama